# Converting a list of Strings into one single integer

Tags: python, string, list, integer

I have a list like this one:

```
 ["1", "8", "9", "5", "6"]
```

And want to convert it into a single integer.
So the desired output is this: `18956`

Is there an elegant method to do this?

The only way which is coming into my mind is going through the list and multiplying the digit with the needed power of ten and adding all up. But I am sure there is a much better method, is not it?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: `int(''.join(["1", "8", "9", "5", "6"]))`

Comment: Thanks for all your fast help. Sorry that I was not able to get that solution on my own...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This does what you want:

It joins each digit into a single string using `''` (an empty string) as a separator, yielding '18956'.

It then converts the string into an integer using the `int()` factory function:

```
int(''.join(["1", "8", "9", "5", "6"]))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int(''.join(["1", "8", "9", "5", "6"]))
```

It's really easy but I'm going to explain it:

First, `join` takes every element of a list and create a string with all elements "joined" by a separator char; as we don't need any separator, we put `''`.

Second, it takes the result string `"18956"` and cast to int

Answer (score 1):

Your list:

```
l = ["1", "8", "9", "5", "6"]
```

Method 1:

```
print(int(''.join(map(str,l))))
```

Method 2:

```
digit = lambda nums: int(''.join(i for i in nums))
print(digit(l))
```

Both outputs are same:

```
18956
18956
```

Comment: Why would you call the `str` function on the numbers when they are already strings?

Comment: True. Edited @JohanL

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
>>> a = ["1", "8", "9", "5", "6"]
>>> num = "".join(a)
>>> num
'18956'
>>> number = int(num)
>>> number
18956
```